# What are the possibilities when you need to wait for a loop to finish executing before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, promise

I have a simple for loop like the following one :

```
var array = [];

for (var key in results) {
    con.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?', [results[key]], function (err, res, fie) {
        array.push(res);
    });
}

res.json({result: array});
```

The code in the loop takes time to execute so the result is sent before the loop has time to finish and therefore the value of my array is incorrect.

I looked it up but couldn't find a proper response to this case. I wanted to know what were the possibilities I had for my code to wait for the loop to completely execute before continuing ?

Thanks, any help much appreciated

Comment: You should use promises.

Comment: I cannot see that the result would be "sent" before the loop has finished. Unless you are leaving out some important information.

Comment: Does the loop use asynchronous code?

Comment: You will have to show us your actual code for us to be able to help you here.  The code you've shown so far is synchronous so it all executes before the `for` loop is done.  If you do have async code in the loop, then you need to show it to us and we can advise the best way to handle it.

Comment: I have updated my code. I am doing a db call in the for loop which explains why the code is async.

Comment: Which database is it?  I need to lookup the promise interface for that DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you never let jfriend know what database you are using, here's something that should work

```
// a "promisified" con.query ... though, not sure what the `fie` argument is
// as it's not used, it wont matter

const queryP = (sql, ...args) => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        con.query(sql, ...args, (err, res, fie) => 
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)
        )
    );
```

Now, your code can be written

```
results // if results is an Object, use: Object.values(results) instead
.map(result => queryP('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?', result))
.then(result => res.json({result}));
```